# 'expr: syntax error: unexpected argument' - result from alias

Tags: bash, alias, expr

I recently added an alias to my .bash_aliases file:

```
alias runhole="perfect && cd data_series_test && doa=$(ls -1 | wc -l) && a=$(expr $doa / 2 ) && perfect && cd data_series_train && dob=$(ls -1 | wc -l) && b=$(expr $dob / 2 ) && perfect && python3 train.py > results_$b'_'$a"
```

and now when I open my terminal I have the error echoed twice:

```
expr: syntax error: unexpected argument ‘2’
expr: syntax error: unexpected argument ‘2’
```

I wanted to output a file called **results_a_b** where a and b are values defined in counting the files in folders defined in the alias, but instead the command outputs **results__**

Comment: Though looking at the whole thing, you'd be better of ditching the single quotes inside the alias and instead using single quotes for the alias: `alias runhole='perfect && cd data_series_test && doa=$(ls -1 | wc -l) && a=$(expr $doa / 2 ) && perfect && cd data_series_train && dob=$(ls -1 | wc -l) && b=$(expr $dob / 2 ) && perfect && python3 train.py > results_${b}_${a}'`
Or just use a function

Comment: Your variables `$doa`, `$dob`, `$a`, and `$b` are being evaluated when you define the alias, not when you use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aliases are almost always better written as functions. The tricky part here is you chain every command together with `&&` to abort early -- I use `set -e` in a subshell here for the same effect.

```
runhole() {
    ( # run in a subshell to avoid side-effects in the current shell
        set -e
        perfect
        cd data_series_test
        doa=$( files=(*); echo "${#files[@]}" )
        a=$(( doa / 2 ))
        perfect
        cd data_series_train
        dob=$( files=(*); echo "${#files[@]}" )
        b=$(( dob / 2 ))
        perfect
        python3 train.py > "results_${b}_$a"
    )
}
```